# What kind of Crassula is this?

Tags: identification, succulents

I've scoured the internet to try and find what variety of Crassula this is, and the closest I could find was Crassula Haemispherica.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What makes you think its a Crassula? Looks more like an Echeveria variety to me, not sure which variety but it has the look of one that would have  darker leaves in sunlight. There are literally thousands of varieties,some with very thick leaves, others with thinner ones like yours, some sample pics here, Pic 3 most similar to yours,  though it isn't the one http://www.thesucculentgarden.com.au/echev3.html

Answer (score 1):

It is Echeveria 'Perle Von Nürnberg' and it looks like it could use more light as it shows signs of etiolation: less upright habit and color loss on the leaves. If you search on the internet you will find slightly different pictures because plants are kept in various conditions (light, humidity), but [this picture](http://exotic-cactus-collection.ecrater.com/p/12480014/echeveria-perle-von-nurnberg-rare#) looks very much like your plant.

[image]